# How to create a drg & drop feature in an iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, drag-and-drop

I am just trying to create a sample ipad app where i have some objects present in left side of my screen which i want that user can able to drag those objects and drop it into right side main view.Then they can able to view and interact with that object.

How can i able to do this please elaborate?

Is there any sample/open source application available which i can refer for this?

Comment: what do you mean by objects  here?

Comment: Objects like a bar chart, Pie chart...etc present in left part of screen when they are drag and drop to right side of screen user can able to interact with them change their shape etc.

Comment: dragging is other thing and changing shapes are other thing .dragging and moving them to the new location can be done by following answer.Now if you want to change the shape through code then it is perfect but if you want that shape can be change by drawing then you have to do some extra efforts for that.

Comment: See [Apple sample app Touches](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to add some other library .You have to implement touches method.
IN touch began you will get the position of the object.IN touch move you will modify the coordinate of that object and on touch ended when you left you will get you object at new position. and you can access your object properly.

ex:-

```
CGPoint startLocation;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
     CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
     startLocation = pt;
}
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
     CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
     CGRect frame = [self frame];
     frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
     frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
     [self setFrame:frame];
}
```

You need to do something like this.